# No data sources are configured to run this SQL [ phpstorm ]

Tags: php, mysql

My code has no problem 
But information is not sent to the database (phpstorm, mysql)

Error text:

> ```
> { No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu }
> ```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn'])) {
  $user_name = $_POST['user_lname'];
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_test');
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (lastname) VALUES ('$user_name')";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="user_lname">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="btn"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you configure a data source in PHPStorm

Comment: post the code here not image use code tag.

Comment: @MohdAlomar there is no code to show. He just has to configure data sources in phpstorm. This has nothing to do with php/mysql. It's strctly related to his editor

Comment: @Indra but he posted a screenshot with code inside it, better to have the code posted not as screenshot.

Comment: @MohdAlomar yeah, but if you read the description you find out it's not related to sql

Comment: @Indra my comment is on question structure not on the question as I don't phpstorm,

Comment: @MohdAlomar his question is related to en editor (phpstorm in this case) and has nothing to do with programming so it's off topic.

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm tries to check your SQL Code against your database. This answer explains how to turn it off:

[How to disable highlighting for SQL code in phpstorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592354/how-to-disable-highlighting-for-sql-code-in-phpstorm/22592721#22592721)